# Customize Scroll bar, scrolling text box-wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, scroll

I have a scrolling text box on a Wordpress site. The text get scrolled by the user sliding the  vertical scroll bar for it.

Is there a way I can change the color of the vertical slide bar and the background for it?
This is the code I used to get the box

```
<div style="border: 4px solid #ffff00; overflow: auto; height: 150px; width: 640px; color:     white; background-color: #32cd32;">
<div style="text-align: left;">
<h1>Text</h1>
```

Text here text here text here text here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to [CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/E6GC6/2/embedded/result/

CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Note: This only works in `-webkit-` browsers (Safari, Chrome)

Comment: Thanks. Like that, yes. Question: I add the above to my css, what do I change in my above code that I still put on the page where it goes?

Comment: @user3041174 Why? you don't need to change anything. I had copied over your [HTML code](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/E6GC6/2/) and added some text to it.

Comment: wasnt sure if i had to add like an id to my actually text box on the page so it knew to use it. I see I dont, but it changes the browser window scroll bar as well and not just the text box. Again, thanks now I just need to change the coloring. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Yes You Can
I Found A Piece Of Code Here
with tutorial.
http://www.techforty.com/2014/02/How-to-change-the-color-of-scrollbars.html

Comment: this is not an answer just suggestion, so better put it as a comments.

Comment: Will Remember In Future . I Am A newbie here.